# How to find all items in a sorted List<T> using .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

How can I find all items in a sorted collection?

Basically I have a `List<T>` collection (large one). First I want to sort it so that the subsequent calls for finding all matches could be performed as fast as possible. i would like to use some build-in mechanisms rather than performing manual searches.

I initially used `FindAll` but that probably will enumerate the entire collection and I need to speed it up.

It has to be done under **.NET 2.0**

**EDIT**

1. I have a collection: `List<Custom>`

Custom is a class with 3 `public` fields (it is a container)

2. Then I sort it:

   `collection.Sort((x, y) => x.Id.CompareTo(y.Id));` // Id is a `Guid`
3. Now I need to find all items in a collection by Id without 
   enumerating all items in a collection.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, you want to find all?  That is counterintuitive...you already have the entire list. Also what type is the sorted collection and what is it sorted with as a `Comparer`?

Comment: Instead of using a list, it might be better to use a [hashtable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.80).aspx) instead.

Comment: A hashtable won't handle duplicates.

Comment: Do you have duplicate id's?

Comment: yes i have duplicates

Comment: Then you need to manually build a data structure for this, a `Dictionary<Guid, List<ElementType>>` will do.

Comment: Really? nothing can be done with just a poor List<T> collection under .net2.0? That collection is huge and rebuilding into Dictionary will also be time consuming task :/

Comment: A binary search, and look at neighbouring items, but nothing built in, no.

Comment: Ehh it is surprisingly funny ...

Comment: What about: Sort and then, FindIndex and manually interate through next rows until I find no matching record?

Comment: @John Probably the time you're wasting since me and others have provided you a similar solution is the time that you could use to implement this refactoring and go forward with your problem :\

Answer (score 2):

`IEqualityComparer<T>` and `IEquatable<T>` interfaces have been available since .NET 2.0 and this framework version introduced [generic dictionaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.80).aspx): `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

What you can do is *indexing*. For example, if you want to get your objects *by id* in a constant time, in addition to adding them to your list, you can add them to a `Dictionary<Guid, Custom>`.

Now you can get objects by id in a constant time:

```
Custom custom = all[someGuid];
```

This approach can be followed by the rest of your class properties.

Why I've talked about `IEqualityComparer<T>` and `IEquatable<T>`? Because if one of the whole properties is another custom class, maybe you'll need to implement one of the so-called interfaces (and/or override `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode`) to implement a custom equality, so dictionary keys will be unique.

If you want to combine more than a property, maybe you'll need to define a class to provide one or more properties:

```
public class Args
{
    public CustomA CustomA;
    public CustomB CustomB; 
}
```

...and you can implement an `IEqualityComparer<T>` for `Args` to provide a combined hash code and be able to use `Args` as dictionary key. This would be like looking for an object which matches all provided properties in a given `Args` instance... (i.e. like using an `&&` operator in a where clause...).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Sort from the Collections namespace? Try providing a Comparer.

[List.Sort Method () .NET Framework 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes that is what I have done so far. But the next thing is I need to find all matches by sorted column (and that has to be done quickly).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a 2D array instead of sorted list, where the first dimension is the GUIDs?

OR

Sort the list, use IndexOf to get the first index of your GUID. Then, use RemoveRange to remove all items before the index you got. And lastly, use Find on the remaining range to get the first GUID that doesn't match your GUID.

Answer (score 0):

See here: [LINQ support on .NET 2.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/linq-support-on-net-2-0)

The easiest way I can think of is to use Linq:

wrong way

```
 List<Order> objListOrder = new List<Order>();
    GetOrderList(objListOrder); // fill list of orders
```

Right way

```
List<Order> SortedList = objListOrder.OrderBy(o=>o.OrderDate).ToList();
```

*Use LINQ with .NET Framework 2.0*

[LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) (from the author of the excellent LINQPad) is a small 60KB assembly that when combined with the multi-targeting capabilities of Visual Studio 2008 gives the ability to write code which does LINQ to Objects (not XML or SQL) but runs fine on a machine with just the .NET Framework 2.0 installed. Very clever

Comment: In my situation i cannot add linq bridge. I also need to find all matches on sorted list. That is the worse thing which don't know how to write.